# What color was the bear?

Tags: lateral-thinking, geography

My grandfather had a very tough and interesting life. He was born in one city, some years later went to school in another city, and finally lived and worked in a third city. He was lucky though to die in exactly the same city he was born in.  Just before he died, he told me his only regret was that he wished he had travelled more.  Especially, he would have liked to see more than one city in his life.

So, [what color was the bear](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-color-was-the-bear)?

Comment: White. It's a polar bear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What color was the bear](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-color-was-the-bear)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that...at least if it is, it's worded horribly.

Comment: It's clearly not a duplicate of that question, but it's not at all clear in what spirit the question is posed.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with polar bears.

Comment: Except for the last word, it has nothing to do with bears of any variety.

Comment: Maybe rewording the last words to "I wish I had not lived my whole life in one city" might help

Comment: Or dropping the non-sequitir about a bear, and just making the puzzle about the city.

Comment: @dennisdeems IMO it's not a total non-sequitur, because Russia itself (herself?) *is* traditionally symbolised by a bear. I think I've heard this one before, somewhere.

Comment: This is one of those questions where it doesn't make any sense until you see the answer, and then you slap your forehead at the logic. It is labeled lateral-thinking and geography, so you have two hints that the  clues are there. It's a matter of figuring out how a guy can visit three cities without ever leaving a city.

Comment: It would be only slightly better if it said "What color was his pet bear" or something else that placed the bear at the general scene of the city.

Comment: He was born in Chicago, got blinded during a mugging, travelled twice, came back and died. The bear is navy blue and orange and terrible.

Comment: He lived in three cities, but never saw them because they were enveloped in eternal darkness, so the bear was black (as was everything)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The color of the bear is brown.

> It is a Russian bear.
>
>  Your grandfather was born in St. Petersburg, went to school in
>  Petrograd, worked in Leningrad, and died in St. Petersburg.

Comment: Other candidates for the place of birth include Khashuri and Senaki (both in Georgia); Karakol in Kyrgyzstan; Hîncești in Moldova; Alchevsk in Ukraine. Some of these require slightly looser interpretation of the question than others. There are even more candidates if we assume unrealistic longevity.

Comment: About Kashuri: wikipedia tells me that Kashuri became a city in 1921, and was named Stalinisi from 1928 to 1934. Was there indeed another renaming?

Comment: Yes, [to Mikhailovo in 1872](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_city_name_changes#.C2.A0Georgia). I didn't focus much on town/city distinctions because they don't necessarily translate well across languages and administrative cultures.

Comment: How did you find out about the cities?

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

> I think your grandfather lived in Saint Petersburg. It was named Petrograd from 1914 to 1924 and Leningrad from 1924 to 1991. I assume bears near Saint Petersburg are brown, but the reference to the story is not clear to me yet.

Comment: Choose your color: http://www.buddy-baer.com/en/united-buddy-bears/world-tour/st-petersburg-2012.html